# Custom Street View

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-street-view

I am trying to create a custom Google street view of a buildings interior. I have looked many places and I have seen the basic idea of how to do it. 
I have been using this link 
http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/custom_streetview/index.html
as well as other examples.
They seem to have very similar code but what they all seem to lack is how to set up the files.
If someone knows where I can find a working example I should be able to work my way backwards of if someone can offer me some detailed instructions, I would be very appreciative.

I have a VirtualBox running an Ubuntu server.

On the server I have an html file named street.html(code below).

I also have a folder named "lab_tiles," which contains "lab_test," which contains several jpegs with the naming pattern XX-YY_s1.jpg(i.e. 00-00_s1.jpg, 00-01_s1.jpg, 00-02_s1.jpg)

I have the following code for the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Street View panorama tiles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function code3_2() {
  // Set StreetView provider.
  var streetViewOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    pano : "lab_test",
    panoProvider:  getCustomPanorama
  };
  // Create a StreetView object.
  var streetViewDiv = document.getElementById('streetview_canvas1');
  streetViewDiv.style.fontSize = "15px";
  var streetView = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(streetViewDiv, streetViewOptions);
}

function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(panoID, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
  // Return a pano image given the panoID.
  return "lab_tiles/" + panoID + '/'  + tileX + '-' +tileY + '_s1.jpg';
}

function getCustomPanorama(panoID) {
  var streetViewPanoramaData = {
    links: [],
    copyright: 'People at my job',
    tiles: {
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        worldSize: new google.maps.Size(2048, 1024),
        centerHeading: 0,
        getTileUrl: getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
     }
  };
  switch(panoID) {
    case "lab_test":
      streetViewPanoramaData["location"] = {
        pano: 'lab_test',
        description: "lab test",
        latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(37.556429,-122.050745)
      };
      return streetViewPanoramaData;
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', code3_2);
    </script>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We figured this out, I am going to post an in depth process when my work schedule clears up.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link you supplied it seems you can put your (tile)images anywhere you want. The function below is used to specify the location when retrieving them.

```
function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(panoID, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
  // Return a pano image given the panoID.
  return "ardenwood_tiles/" + panoID + '/'  + tileX + '-' +tileY + '_s1.jpg';
}
```

In this case the images will be in the folder named ardenwood_tiles/visitor_center/

Comment: I have now tried that, with no success. I have edited my post to be a bit more clear about what I have currently.

Comment: do you see any errormessages? Does anything show? What happens when you name your images like they did in the example? 0-0_si.jpg 0-1_s1.jpg and so on instead of 00-00_s1.jpg, 00-01_s1.jpg, 00-02_s1.jpg